# Find inner index with minimum value in double-index Groupby Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame that, after some groupy operations like:

```
df.groupby(["dataset", "method"])["mae"].mean()
```

it looks like:

```
dataset             method
acute.a             AC        0.003516
                    EDX       0.028901
                    EDy       0.029160
                    HDX       0.040332
                    HDy       0.027015
acute.b             AC        0.003575
                    EDX       0.043130
                    EDy       0.029151
                    HDX       0.016335
                    HDy       0.003692
balance.1           AC        0.012195
                    EDX       0.019322
                    EDy       0.010015
                    HDX       0.018285
                    HDy       0.009011
balance.2           AC        0.179619
                    EDX       0.259377
                    EDy       0.497555
                    HDX       0.444765
                    HDy       0.435202
balance.3           AC        0.028937
                    EDX       0.034840
                    EDy       0.014509
                    HDX       0.037650
                    HDy       0.014660
breast-cancer       AC        0.005540
                    EDX       0.007067
                    EDy       0.006252
                    HDX       0.012012
                    HDy       0.005629
                                ...
```

So now I want to capture the `method` which gives the minimum value (third column) for each `dataset`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for values of `MultiIndex` by `minimal` values per groups and for select second value of tuples add `str[1]`:

```
s = df.groupby(["dataset", "method"])["mae"].mean()

s1 = s.groupby(level=0).idxmin().str[1]
print (s1)
dataset
acute.a           AC
acute.b           AC
balance.1        HDy
balance.2         AC
balance.3        EDy
breast-cancer     AC
Name: mae, dtype: object
```

If need also values select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html):

```
s2 = s.loc[s.groupby(level=0).idxmin()]
print (s2)
dataset        method
acute.a        AC        0.003516
acute.b        AC        0.003575
balance.1      HDy       0.009011
balance.2      AC        0.179619
balance.3      EDy       0.014509
breast-cancer  AC        0.005540
Name: mae, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Than add `.reset_index()`